# Webview Livescope SDK Video Recording in .net

Tags: c#, sdk, webview, canon-sdk

How to record Video of Canon camera VB-C60?
 This is network camera and right now i am using wvls_sdkstng.dll (Webview Livescope SDK) and dll version is 2.1.3 for recording video.

My code is in c#.net. Which function should i use for record video.? I have tried with SaveAsAVI function, it gives me codec 60 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use option **wvlssAviMpeg4** for video

```
conWVSL.SaveAsAvi(filepath, WvlsSDKSmplLib.WvlssAviSupport_t.wvlssAviMpeg4, 1, 10, 180);
```

You can change argument parameter as per your requirement.